# export data from Source system and import to destination system in update mode

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two systems source and destination. both system had same no of tables with same names. But destination system tables had more colums than in source system tables. I want to export source system dump into destination system without updating new colums in destination system.

ex: Source System,

T1->name='a',sex='F', id=1

Destination system

T1->name='a1',sex='F', id=1, email=a@b.com.

I want to import dump in to destination system, update t1 table without updating email field.
How can i do this?

Comment: How many tables you have. If its only for 1 table you can do `Merge`

Comment: it had more than 50 tables

Comment: Then you must create a procedure which takes the input as source,destination table , pk of the tables and use dynamic SQL to merge the columns,

Comment: Can you give me any example of code for that

Comment: See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below my code which i have run on my sample data. please run it in your environment and check if it solve your issue.

Few assumptions:
 1.) TARGET SCHEMA NAME IS @Target_Schema.( In the code replace @Target_schema with your target schema name)
 3.) EACH TABLE IN SOURCE SCHEMA SHOULD HAVE A PK TO UPDATE.
 4.) MAKE SURE NO TABLE IN SOURCE HAS COMPOSITE PK
 5.) YOU SHOULD HAVE DML PRIVILEGES IN TGT SCHEMA FOR PARTICULAR TABLES YOU ARE UPDATING or inserting.

Code:

```
    CREATE TABLE ANK1  
            (
            ID NUMBER,  
            NAME VARCHAR2(4000),
            );  

            ALTER TABLE ank1
            ADD CONSTRAINT ANK_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID);  

            insert into ANK1   values(1,'abc');
            commit;

           CREATE TABLE @Target_Schema.ANK1
            (
           ID NUMBER,
           NAME VARCHAR2(4000),
           EMAIL VARCHAR2(4000)
           );  


    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
declare
p_key_col varchar2(40);
l_merge_sql varchar2(4000);
begin
for cur_tab in ( SELECT * FROM (
SELECT UTC.TABLE_NAME,UTC.COLUMN_NAME,UCC.COLUMN_NAME AS PK_COL  FROM USER_TAB_COLS UTC,USER_CONSTRAINTS UC,USER_CONS_COLUMNS UCC WHERE UTC.TABLE_NAME IN ('ANK1')
AND UTC.TABLE_NAME = UC.TABLE_NAME AND UC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P' AND UC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = UCC.CONSTRAINT_NAME) WHERE PK_COL <> COLUMN_NAME ) loop


    l_merge_sql:= 'MERGE INTO @Target_Schema.'||cur_tab.table_name||' T_TABLE
     USING '||cur_tab.table_name||' SRC
        ON (T_TABLE.'||cur_tab.PK_COL||' = SRC.'||cur_tab.PK_COL||')

     WHEN MATCHED THEN
          UPDATE
             SET T_TABLE.'||cur_tab.COLUMN_NAME||' = SRC.'||cur_tab.COLUMN_NAME||'

     WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          INSERT (T_TABLE.'||cur_tab.PK_COL||', T_TABLE.'||cur_tab.COLUMN_NAME||')
          VALUES (SRC.'||cur_tab.PK_COL||', SRC.'||cur_tab.COLUMN_NAME||')';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_merge_sql);

 END LOOP;

 END;
```

You will get a merge statement printed and you can run that separately to see the results.

Hope this will solve your issue.